# Tornadofx REST client

Tags: json, rest, kotlin, tornadofx

I have followed an example shown here

[link](https://docs.tornadofx.io/0_subsection-1/json_and_rest)

And i got the hang of it, i managed to create my own "Employee" entity and i found some dummy api data online to play with.
[like this](http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees) Problem is, the tornadofx throws null pointer error, and i think its because the rest response sends something like this

```
{
"status": "success",
"data": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "employee_name": "Tiger Nixon",
        "employee_salary": "320800",
        "employee_age": "61",
        "profile_image": ""
    },
```

but when i use [mocky](https://designer.mocky.io/design/confirmation) and provide JUST the json part

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "employee_name": "Tiger Nixon",
        "employee_salary": "320800",
        "employee_age": "61",
        "profile_image": ""
    },...]
```

it all works fine.
I think those additional fields "status" and "success" in response confuse the rest client of tornadofx, and i cant manage to get it to work, is there anyway to tell client to ignore every other fields besides those of json data.

All links are functional, so you can try yourself.

full working example

```
    package com.example.demo.view

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane
import tornadofx.*
import javax.json.JsonObject


class Employee (id:Int?=null , name: String? = null, age: Int?=null): JsonModel  {
    val idProperty = SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "id")
    var id by idProperty
    val ageProperty = SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "age")
    var age by ageProperty

    val employeeNameProperty = SimpleStringProperty(this, "name", name)
    var name by employeeNameProperty
    override fun updateModel(json: JsonObject) {
        with(json) {
            id = int("id")!!
           age = int("employee_age")!!
            name = string("employee_name")

        }
    }

    override fun toJSON(json: JsonBuilder) {
        with(json) {
            add("id", id)
            add("employee_name", name)
            add("employee_age", age)

        }
    }
}

class PersonEditor : View("Person Editor") {
    override val root = BorderPane()
  val api : Rest by inject()
    var persons = listOf(Employee(1,"John", 44), Employee(2,"Jay", 33)).observable()
    val model = PersonModel(Employee())

    init {
        api.baseURI = "https://run.mocky.io/v3/"
        val response = api.get("f17509ba-2d12-4c56-b441-69ab23302e43")

        println(response.list())
        println(response.list().toModel<Employee>()[0].name)


    //   print( p.get(1))
        with(root) {
            center {
                tableview(response.list().toModel<Employee>()) {
                    column("Id", Employee::idProperty)
                    column("Name", Employee::employeeNameProperty)
                    column("Age", Employee::ageProperty)

                    // Update the person inside the view model on selection change
                    model.rebindOnChange(this) { selectedPerson ->
                        item = selectedPerson ?: Employee()
                    }
                }
            }

            right {
                form {
                    fieldset("Edit person") {
                        field("Id") {
                            textfield(model.id)
                        }
                        field("Name") {
                            textfield(model.name)
                        }
                        field("Age") {
                            textfield(model.age)
                        }
                        button("Save") {
                            enableWhen(model.dirty)
                            action {
                                save()
                            }
                        }
                        button("Reset").action {
                            model.rollback()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun save() {
        // Flush changes from the text fields into the model
        model.commit()

        // The edited person is contained in the model
        val person = model.item

        // A real application would persist the person here
        println("Saving ${person.employeeNameProperty} / ${person.ageProperty}")
    }

}
class PersonModel(person: Employee) : ItemViewModel<Employee>(person) {
    val id = bind(Employee::idProperty)
    val name = bind(Employee::employeeNameProperty)
    val age = bind(Employee::ageProperty)
}
```

if you replace base url and  send request to http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees you will get an error that i am talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to mocky returns a list, so `.list()` works fine. Your call to restapiexample, however, returns an object, not a list, so `.list()` won't do what you expect. You can probably use something like this, though I haven't tested it:

```kotlin
response.one().getJsonArray("data").toModel<Employee>()[0].name)
```

---

Further explanation:

*If you're not familiar with the structure of JSON, check out the diagrams on [the JSON homepage](https://www.json.org/).*

TornadoFX has two convenience functions for working with JSON returns: `.list()` and `.one()`. The `.list()` function will check if the result is a `JsonArray`. If so, it simply returns it. If it is instead a `JsonObject`, it wraps that object in a list and returns the new list.

In your case, since restapiexample is returning an object, the result of your call to `.list()` is a JsonArray with a single object. It looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    "status": "success",
    "data": [...]
  }
]
```

Obviously that single object cannot be converted to an `Employee`, so dereferencing anything off of it will result in a `NullPointerException`.

The `.one()` function on the other hand will check if the response is a `JsonObject`. If it is, it simply returns the object. If, however, the response is a `JsonArray`, it will take the first item from the array and return that item.